# Paperclip Rails 4 Reprocess attr_accessor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

My rails 4 application is having some issues with the paperclip reprocess method. I have a custom Cropper module:

```
module Paperclip
  class Cropper < Thumbnail
    def transformation_command
      if crop_command
        crop_command + super.sub(/ -crop \S+/, '')
      else
        super
      end
    end

    def crop_command
      target = @attachment.instance
      if target.cropping?
        ratio = target.avatar_geometry(:original).width  / target.avatar_geometry(:large).width
        ["-crop", "#{(target.crop_w.to_i*ratio).round}x#{(target.crop_h.to_i*ratio).round}+#{(target.crop_x.to_i*ratio).round}+#{(target.crop_y.to_i*ratio).round}"]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And I have a few attr_accessors for the crop_x, crop_y, crop_w, crop_h.

I'm running into an issue with having crop_x, y, w, and h available when it hits the cropper class. Those elements are always nil even if in the controler (during the update method) that these aren't nil.

I believe this has to do with them be attr_accessors, so I'm looking for some advice as to how to handle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the controller that handles the update, did you include :crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h as permitted parameters?

you should have something like this:

```
params.require(:model).permit(:attribute1, :attribute2, :crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h)
```

Comment: Yes. I'm thinking this might be solved by making a job and having a worker do this. Because if I change the code around, the code will fail on the image not being loaded yet. If I add a job, then this data would be kept in the db? Maybe that would be better?